# Is there an option in SalesForce where you can define what gets returned from Web-to-Case?

Tags: web2case

The current Web-to-Case setup doesn't get an "object" back from SalesForce indicating whether or not it was a success, but rather plain/HTML text. Typically an object or an array would be returned that would give some sort of code or 'success' data element.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you do get a success response back; it's in the headers. It's been a while since I've used it, but there should be a header like `X-Success: true`. Please note that this success does not mean a case was successfully created. It only means that the case was successfully queued in the Web-to-Case system, and will be asynchronously processed later. There's no way to know if the case was created from the response, since it will be not created before you get a response.